# Form for creating instance of nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

How does one go about creating an associated model instance outside the parent model?

I have a nested resource

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :users do
    resources :messages
end

# models/user.rb
has_many :messages
# some other user model specifications

# models/messages.rb
belongs_to :user
```

I followed the authentication procedures introduced in RailsTutorial.org; so I have a helper called `current_user` that returns the user that is signed in. This method is in a `SessionsHelper` module included in the `ApplicationController`

```
# views/messages/new
= form_for current_user.messages.build do |f|
```

This line in the view spits out an error

```
undefined method 'messages_path' for #<#<Class:0xHex_Number>:0xHex_Number
```

The idea is to allow users send messages amongst themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the view layer error by building a placeholder message in the view.

```
= form_for current_user.messages.build, :url new_user_message_path(:user_id => current_user do |f|
```

This enabled a form to be rendered but when I submitted the form, the browser sent a POST request to the `new` action. The console log read...

```
Started POST "/users/1/messages/new" for 127.0.0.1 at ...

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/users/1/messages/new"):
```

...which is obviously wrong. According to the REST theory, a function that receives a get request should not respond to a POST request i.e. functions should be *request-specific*.

To fix this, I changed the following:

```
# controllers/messages
   def new
++   @message = Message.new
   end

# views/messages/new
-- form_for current_user.messages.build, :url new_user_message_path(:user_id => current_user do |f|
++ form_for [current_user, @message] do |f|
```

This way, on submission, the create function receives a POST request. In the console...

```
Started POST "/users/1/messages" for 127.0.0.1 at ...
  Processing by MessagesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"areallylongstringthatnobodycanguess", "utf8"=>"✓", "message"=>{"title"=>"This is a breakthrough", "recipient"=>"Jamie", "content"=>"can you believe the developers got the messaging system working???"}, "user_id"=>"1"}
Completed   in 5ms
```

...as expected.